# Samba share for everyone inside network

Tags: networking, mount, permissions, samba

I'm sure this is really easy but can get it working and don't know if it's some kind of permisson or what.

I have one disk mounted as a backup disk in my "server" machine, and want to share this directory  with everyone in the network. There are many machines, some with Windows and some with Ubuntu.

Here is smb.conf of the server machine.

```
[global]
   workgroup = 1
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
#   wins support = no
;   wins server = w.x.y.z
   dns proxy = no


####### Authentication #######
   encrypt passwords = true
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user

########## Domains ###########
;   domain logons = yes


############ Misc ############
   usershare allow guests = yes

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no

[backups]
        comment = Backups
        path = /media/backups
        writeable = yes
        browseable = yes
        guest ok = yes
        create mask = 0777
        directory mask = 0777
```

In the other Ubuntu machines I mount them in /etc/fstab like

```
//server/backups  /srv/backups  cifs  guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8  0  0
```

Windows machines can read and write without problems, but I can't get Ubuntu machines to do the same thing.

Do I have to give some permisson to the server folder with chmod to get this working? Maybe I need to give some kind of permisson in mount path of the others Ubuntu machines? Cause I tried a lot of combinations of chmod/chown and can't get it working!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add the contents of `cat /usr/local/etc/smb.conf` to your question?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay Mitch, I update post with the full smb.conf.